# Unable to Debug Lambda locally in Rider

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm using Jetbrains Rider with Mock Lambda Test Tool and for some reason I am unable to Debug my code with the tool - the Debug button in Rider is just greyed out:

[image]

Here is my Run/Debug Configuration:

[image]

And this is my launchSettings.json file:

[image]

The Mock Lambda Test Tool launches fine in the browser fine when just clicking "Run", but can't Debug in that mode.

Any help or pointers would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by using .NET Executable instead of .Net Launch Settings Profile.

I set the Exe path to to be `C:/Users/$(USERNAME)/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1/0.10.1/amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1/0.10.1/tools/netcoreapp3.1/any/Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.WebTester31.dll`

And the working directory as the Project Root of my Lambda project.

Comment: Just for what its worth, when using version 0.11.3 your initial launch settings worked for me even though thats not what is stated in their documentation.
Bless you for posting this, I spent hours trying to run a lambda locally and this is the first post I see that mentions using mock tool

Comment: With .net 6 I tried this solution but didn't like the part of having to use the absolute path to the project (no macro support from Rider here). The solution from @abutir is better so that you can use MSBuild macros.

Answer (score 3):

my launchSettings.json seems like the following,

```
{
"profiles": {
"Mock Lambda Test Tool vs2022": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "commandLineArgs": "--port 5050",
  "workingDirectory": ".\\bin\\$(Configuration)\\netcoreapp3.1",
  "executablePath": "%USERPROFILE%\\.dotnet\\tools\\dotnet-lambda-test-tool-3.1.exe",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "TABLE_PREFIX": "dev"
  }
},
"Mock Lambda Test Tool Rider": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "commandLineArgs": "--port 5050",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "executablePath": "%USERPROFILE%\\.dotnet\\tools\\.store\\amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1\\0.11.4\\amazon.lambda.testtool-3.1\\0.11.4\\tools\\netcoreapp3.1\\any\\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.BlazorTester.dll",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "TABLE_PREFIX": "dev"
  }
}
}
}
```

And it works like a charm with Rider

Comment: This worked for me in 2022 as well but after a Rider update somewhere in 2023 I had to change to the solution from @abutir

Answer (score 2):

For future devs , if it is still not working , this worked for me :

the $(ProjectDir) is not set anywhere keep it like that it will take an empty value

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Mock Lambda Test Tool Rider": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "commandLineArgs": "C:\\Users\\{HERE_COMES_YOUR_USER}\\.dotnet\\tools\\.store\\amazon.lambda.testtool-6.0\\0.14.1\\amazon.lambda.testtool-6.0\\0.14.1\\tools\\net6.0\\any\\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.BlazorTester.dll --port 5050",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "executablePath": "dotnet"
    }
  }
}
```

make sure the command line args is same on your machine . i have .net 6.0